# Dont remove pub/static content in setup:upgrade command

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content

It is possible to keep pub/static folder as it is after run setup:upgrade command.

Becuase I have multilanguage site and every time when we add new module I run upgrade command and run content deploy for every language.

So it is possible to keep pub/static content during setup:upgrade command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can tell Magento not to get rid of generated code and static files:

```
magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

From [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-db-upgr.html):

> where --keep-generated is an optional argument that does not update
>   static view files. This optional argument is for use only in limited
>   circumstances by experienced system integrators. It should be used
>   only in production mode. It should not be used in developer mode.

Please note you can get into trouble doing this if you're not careful. I would stick to using the proper deployment process.

Why do you want to avoid deleting the file? Is it just to speed up the deployment?